# Pandas: if statement with error: 'single positional indexer is out-of-bounds' then else

Tags: python, pandas

What I would like to do is the following:

`if` `df.loc[df['proba'] <= proba_plus].iloc[0]` is not `single positional indexer is out-of-bounds`

then: `gamma_plus = df.loc[df['proba'] <= proba_plus].iloc[0]`

`else` `gamma_plus =df['gamma'].max()`

Any idea on how to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `if-else` statement with [`Series.empty`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.empty.html):

```
a = df.loc[df['proba'] <= proba_plus, 'gamma']
gamma_plus = df['gamma'].max() if a.empty else a.iat[0]
```

Or use `next` with `iter` - there is possible set default value if empty `Series`:

```
a = df.loc[df['proba'] <= proba_plus, 'gamma']
gamma_plus = next(iter(a, df['gamma'].max()))
```